# how to Upload documents to sharepoint 2013 and their older versions?

Tags: 2013, file-upload, versioning

We are moving away from a platform storing documents to store them on sharepoint 2013, but this documents have a lot of previous versions that we want to keep

is there a way to upload the previous versions of those files and also keep the dates when those versions were modified?

Answer (score 0):

You could bang out a powershell script that loops through your folder and uploads the oldest file first, then add each one with the loop since SharePoint allows you to add each file as a new version you would be able to stack them. But this of course depends on how or where they are stored now. The question would be does the system you have now allow you to browse the folders where they are stored or can you invoke an option to download the document and all revisions to some network share.